# How do I deploy an AWS Serverless Application Model template with boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cloudformation, serverless-architecture

I've written a package that will render SAM templates in Python but I cannot deploy them. Every time I try create_stack, create_change_set, or execute_change_set I'm met with errors.

Comment: code and error trace please!

Answer (score -2):

I think On AWS server less Application model template use with AWS Lambda. 
Here is somthing interesting for you. try it;
[aws-step-functions-a-serverless-orchestrator](http://cloudacademy.com/blog/aws-step-functions-a-serverless-orchestrator/)